# HTML5 Canvas Drag and Drop with snap into position images

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-animals-on-the-beach-game-with-kineticjs

I am wanting to have this for my HTML5 IOS Application. This requires the widget work offline. When I change line 16, I change the source to "../img/art/" as this is where the images are located. Upon doing this, the entire application disappears. Why?

If there is not a solution, is there a code that will allow me to do the same concept?

Answer (score 0):

Try without the '../'

I suggest using Chrome's console to check if you have any errors - like image failed to load. This will at least let you know your path is wrong.